# Why does ios build don't show in test flight even though it is a success

Tags: ios, app-store-connect

Yesterday I submitted a new version of my app to the app store connect. Even thought it shows a success I can't see my build versions. I have not received an email of whether they received the build or even if it has some errors. Also , I can't see their status in test flight. Is this normal because previously i did not have this problem

[image]

testflight showing older versions

[image]

After I submit binary processing appears then like the following pic

[image]

then after I refresh the page the build never shows

[image]

Comment: Is it possible to push your build making `version 1.7 (1)`?

Comment: I pushe version 1.4(1) and 1.5(1) till 1.6 and nothing happnes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My builds started to appear after 24 hours

Answer (score 0):

Can you try from terminal approach using following command.

- First export you `ipa` file
- Enter this command in terminal

  > `xcrun altool –upload-app -f /location-to-your-ipa-file/app-name.ipa  -t platform -u your_email_address -p app-specific-password`

You will need to create `app specific password` for this to work. Please note, this is not preferred approach. Let's see what happens in your case.

#### Steps to create password:

- First of all you will need to login to https://appleid.apple.com.
  Under Security, click Generate Password...
- Give a label as you want.
- Click Create button.
- Now you will see the app-specific password. Copy that password. [Click here](https://cdn.statically.io/img/santoshm.com.np/wp-content/uploads/2020/12/steps.jpg?quality=100&f=auto) to see the image.
- Don’t close the terminal until it say successful.

Comment: ok I will give this a try and I will get back to you soon

Comment: quick question what is the platform in command line tool

Comment: Didn't get you. Platform?

Comment: Ok I got the following No errors uploading '***app.ipa' but I still cant find build folder

Comment: Can you click on the build  in testflight and click expire button and try again uploading new build. [Steps in image](https://dropover.cloud/46b056)

Comment: It doesnot appear on test flight only older versions that are expired thats my problem.i cant see my builds even as processing

Comment: If that doesn't work, can you try removing yourself from tester and add again and try again uploading the build.

Comment: You mean remove my self as a user

Comment: Yes. Please refer to [this image](https://dropover.cloud/d3c802).

Comment: Ok i will do a new build and submit and get back to you

Comment: it doesnot work too. My app has a non consumble in app purchase could that be the reason. Does in app purchase need to be reviewed first

Comment: @Ahmed no, you should see it in testflight at least. I have the same problem as you, i wonder if it's a problem with App store now. I think they recently updated it

Comment: check my question i made an edit processing appears for a while then disappears

Comment: @Ahmed Yeah i have the same problem. i dont check the status page after i upload, but xcode says it uploads successfully. I check the testflight tab after 1 hour and nothing is there. It seems someone else is having this issue as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67893368/newly-uploaded-builds-not-appearing-or-processing-in-app-store-connect

Comment: I think everything is all good in your process. And app upload shows success too. So, it would be better to wait some time to show up again.