# Newly uploaded builds not appearing or processing in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect

I've uploaded several builds over the past 48 hours and none of them are appearing nor processing in App Store Connect. The builds have uploaded successfully through Xcode. Has anyone else experienced this and know a potential resolution? I've submitted a support ticket with Apple but I'm hoping for a quicker resolution. Thanks in advance for any insight.

Comment: I am facing the same issue with no solution at all here is my problem and I submitted a ticket with no resolution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67888536/why-does-ios-build-dont-show-in-test-flight-even-though-it-is-a-success

Comment: Same problem here, haven't been able to see a new build for the past 24-48 hrs. I did notice an updated agreement, which I accepted, but still no joy.

Comment: I submitted more than 10 builds to an existing app and I can't see them. I tried submitting a build for a new app and it worked. I don't know what is the problem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give your builds 24-48 hours to appear mine already started to appear

Comment: They all started coming in now. Thanks

Comment: Mine took about 10 minutes but it's there now.

Answer (score 1):

Followed these steps:

1. Please check your mail...apple reports issue regarding your app in your mail..Try fixing them.
2. In my case, I added these following in my info.plist:

```html
<key>NSPhotoLibraryUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the photo library.</string>
<key>NSMicrophoneUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app does not require access to the microphone.</string>
<key>NSCameraUsageDescription</key>
<string>This app requires access to the camera.</string>
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: I don't know why, but disabling this option while distributing app helped me]

I don't know why, but disabling this option while distributing app helped me